# Spring-Integration TCP --> eh-cache chain

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-integration

I have a Spring-Integration TCP server with request and response and it works correctly. Well now I have to add a new layer to my application.

I have to put my message to an eh-cache db and then send back the ACK. Currently I have only a tcp clients but in the future I will have other sources, as the schema below.

[image]

Now the question is:
Can I configure this behavior using Spring-Integration? 
I know that I can  take the message on my  `‘importService’` and put it on my eh-cache writing a code in this way:

```
public MyMessage handler(MyMessage message) {
        try {
            myCache.put(mykey, message)
            } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("unable to update" + e);
            }
        return message;
    }
```

but I think it is not properly correct, and I was just wondering if I can configure my spring configuration file and add another end-point in order to create a chain.
My current config-file is:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverTcpConFact"  type="server"  port="5566"  using-nio="false"        single-use="false"
  so-receive-buffer-size="8192"
    so-send-buffer-size="8192"
    so-tcp-no-delay="true"
    task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
    deserializer="serializer" 
    serializer="serializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundAdapter"
    channel="tcpInbound"
    connection-factory="serverTcpConFact" />

<int:channel id="tcpInbound" />

<int:service-activator 
    output-channel="tcpOutbound" 
    input-channel="tcpInbound"
    ref="importService"
    method="handler" />

<bean id="importService" class="com.MyImportService" />

<int:channel id="tcpOutbound" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="mygateway"
    request-channel="tcpInbound"
    reply-channel="tcpOutbound"
    reply-timeout="6"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="tcpOutboundAdapter"
    channel="tcpOutbound"
    connection-factory="serverTcpConFact" />
```

I was looking the public examples but I didn’t find an eh-cache example and a chain example.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like it just enough to move you Cache logic to the `ChannelInterceptor`:

```
<int:channel id="tcpInbound">
   <int:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.my.proj.si.CachePutChannelInterceptor"
   </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

And use this interceptor from any place when you need to use Cache.

Comment: I moved it on My tcpOutbound, And it works fine. Thank you @Artem.